# Return first not null result from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQL Server, I have the following query (minimized):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.OWNER, B.CAR
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.ID = B.CAR_ID
```

Which returns the following:

```
ID   Owner   Car
01   Bob     BMW
02   Bob     NULL
03   Bob     BMW
04   Andy    Audi
05   Andy    Audi
```

I want to Group By Owner with the first not NULL result for car to get:

```
Owner   Car
Bob     BMW
Andy    Audi
```

I could do:

```
SELECT A.OWNER, max(B.CAR) as Car
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.ID = B.CAR_ID
GROUP BY A.OWNER
```

But, is there way to do this with Coalesce()? Or something else that might work better with a more complex query?

Comment: You've done it correctly assuming max suits your needs.

Comment: The first not null meaning when you sort the whole thing by ID?

Comment: Edit your question and show your original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a car is present, your result-set always associates 'Bob' with 'BMD' and 'Andy' with 'Audi'.  I assume, however, that in the real dataset there are owners that can have more than one type of car.  So the question then becomes: "which one do you choose?".

If it's really arbitrary and doesn't matter, then your existing approach using 'max' is fine.  At least it has a predictable default ordering so that you'll get the same output on every run given the same state of data in the base tables.

However, if something else should count as 'first', such as if you wanted to base the comparison on the 'id' field, then you're going to want to use 'row_number' to order by that field for within each owner, such as in the code below.

```
select      owner, car
from        (
                select      *, 
                            ord = row_number() over(partition by owner order by id)
                from        [Table A] a
                left join   [Table B] b on a.id = b.car_id
                where       b.car is not null
            ) orderings
where       ord = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by first result. If you want to go by the default order, you could do:
If you were ordering by ID, then it would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(Owner) OVER(PARTITION BY Owner ORDER BY ID), FIRST_VALUE(Car) OVER(PARTITION BY Owner ORDER BY ID)
FROM Table_Name WHERE Car IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This would give a resultset in which Bob and Andy each have two rows.  You could perhaps wrap it all into a subquery and then do a 'select distinct *' in the outer query.  Also, 'first_value' requires an 'order by' clause, so your first example would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES A.OWNER, B.CAR
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.ID = B.CAR_ID
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.OWNER ORDER IIF(B.CAR IS NOT NULL, 0, 1), A.ID)
```

By splitting the `ORDER BY` in two, you place all `NULL`'s last, followed by ordering on the given ID in your resultset. Each distinct `A.OWNER` will receive `ROW_NUMBER()` 1. Using `TOP 1 WITH TIES` you're left with all 1's without using a subquery, thus having only one row per `A.OWNER`.